# is there any way to put Cardview inside Horizontalscrollview?

Tags: horizontalscrollview, android-cardview

I have an horizontalScrollView with some card style view inside.
there are image and textview inside the card style view.

I used to do it by manually creating a new linearlayout and put the image and text inside the view programmally.

the card style code is like below:

```
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext());
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(PixeltoDp(100),PixeltoDp(180));
        //params.setMargins(PixeltoDp(10),PixeltoDp(5),PixeltoDp(10), PixeltoDp(5));
        params.setMargins(10,5,10,5);
        //layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(280,400));// single container
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
        layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_card);

        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext());
        imageView............


        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        ...............

        layout.addView(imageView);
        layout.addView(textView);

        return layout;

    }
```

but now, I'd like to use android.support.v7.widget.CardView class to make this. so I can easily customize the layout of the cardview in an cardview.xml file in the layout/ folder. and my cardview layout is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movie_img"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:cropToPadding="false"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_poster" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/movie_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:hint="synaptop"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textColor="#e0e0e0" />
</LinearLayout>
```

the problem is how should i use the layout file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself after all...
just inflat the view

```
    //create ur cardview here and inflate it 
    final CardView mCardView = new CardView(getActivity());
    View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.cardview_layout, mCardView);

    LinearLayout mCardContainer = (LinearLayout)mCardView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_container);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        mCardContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ripple_color_borderless);
    }


    //here u just define whatever u have in ur cardview xml
    final ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) mCardView.findViewById(R.id.movie_img);
    mImageView.setTag(index);
    mImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

and the end, add this view to your horizontalScrollView.